# What is the standard usage argument style?

Tags: command-line-arguments

I'm making some command-line tools for some research I'm doing.  I'd like these tools to follow commonly used conventions regarding command line programs in Unix.

Should I use flags or just list parameters?

```
program one two three
program -a one -b two -c three
```

- Where in the list of commands does the input file normally go, or is it better to `<` it into the program?
- What about the output filename?
- Should I specify the file extension for the output format, or have my program automatically put the correct extension on?
- When the user enters an invalid command, is there a prototypical "correct usage" message?
- Is "--help" or "-h" required?

Also, is there some sort of header file I can include that would help with managing these?

Comment: I think you'll find there's no such thing as a standard for this. Different tools use very different conventions, even on the same OS. Heck, I don't think even all the standard GNU tools use exactly the same convention. The only environment that I know of that enforces a consistent argument convention (because the shell, not the programs, do the parsing) is Microsoft PowerShell.

Comment: I'll settle for "best practices" then.

Comment: @Nick: There aren't any of those either. It's programmers; everyone has their own idea of which is better.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a "standard", then you could do worse than look at [**GNU's Standards for Command Line Interfaces**](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Command_002dLine-Interfaces.html). Other standards are available.

As far as coding for this goes, take a look at [**`boost::program_options`**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/program_options.html). Not only will this save you rolling a lot of your own code, but it does a good job of formatting the options for presenting to the user (the prototypical "correct usage" message, you asked for).

In answer to your specific questions:

> - Where in the list of commands does the input file normally go, or is it better to < it into the program?

I would expect these to come at the end of a command line. Like in GNU `grep`. If you are only processing one file and would like to make `stdin` available as an input source, that would not surprise most users.

If your command processes lots of files, then it would be unusual to have to specify a switch before the filenames. Think `cat`.

> - What about the output filename?

A `-o` or `--output` option is fairly common. If your file takes exactly one input and one output, then `program inputfile outputfile` would not surprise many users. If no output file is specified, perhaps you'll output to `stdout`; that would not be unusual behaviour and would allow your users to pipe the output through other commands (such as `grep`, `less`, *etc...*), They could also redirect stdout to a file using `>`.

> - Should I specify the file extension for the output format, or have my program automatically put the correct extension on?

This is probably a matter for debate. If I specified an output filename, I would expect to find that file created (or replaced, after a prompt) without the program changing the name.

> - When the user enters an invalid command, is there a prototypical "correct usage" message?

Using GNU `grep` as an example again:

```
grep: unrecognized option '--incorrect'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

This wouldn't surprise too many users and points them in the right direction if they've made a typo without swamping them with information.

> - Is "`--help`" or "`-h`" required?

That depends on your customer! I find it frustrating when this option isn't available.

Answer (score 0):

Usually speaking, flags are there for providing options and parameter are for passing information. If you have input,output file as command line argument, use flags like -i -o, so sequence will not matter. -h is required if you want to (and need to)  give documentation.